# how to use foreign key to submit a form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have an address model like this:

```
class PrevAddress(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address_province = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True)
    address_city = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
```

and a mapinfo models which is connected to it using a foreign key relation:

```
class MapInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prevAddress = models.ForeignKey(PrevAddress, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = LocationField(
        map_attrs={
            "style": "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
            "center": (51.3890, 35.6892),
        }, null=True)
    lat = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    long = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

and these are the views I wrote for the mapinfo:

```
class MapInfoView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'reg/map.html'
    model = MapInfo
    fields = ['location']
    success_url = '/profile/contact/prev-addresses'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

the issue is that each mapinfo is related to a prevaddress object and when I want to add a new mapinfo, it needs a prevaddress object id for the connection and gives me this error:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: reg_mapinfo.prevAddress_id.
```

how do I add something like this to the views ... prevaddress.id = mapinfo.id ? I can choose a prevaddress object for the mapinfo from the admin page but users obviously dont have any access to it. please help me

Comment: Your form doesn't have option to choose prevaddress obj ?

Comment: no, it should be automatic. mapinfo.object1.id = prevad.object1.id, mapinfo.object2.id = prevad.object2.id. I need something like this

Comment: Please have a look on how Foreignkey fields are used, You are using it in wrong sense

Comment: Before creating Mapinfo object, you should already have a prevaddress object availabel

Comment: `no, it should be automatic`, you just don't have to provide id, that is actually referencing to whole object, not only the field.

Comment: my problem is the delete function. I want the mapinfo to be deleted when the address one is deleted. thats why I used foreign key. can you help me with the code to accomplish this? if we fix the delete function there would be no problem